# Drawing board game "tokens" to board and datagrid view

Tags: c#, datagrid

I'm currently working on an exercise for my c# class. I am having some trouble with one particular part and would really appreciate some help.

I am working on an exercise in which we are given an incomplete project file. The project was to create a board game which lets up to six people play (fairly simple in theory). The part I am currently stuck on is showing the player "tokens" on  the board.

This is what the final board is meant to look like: [image]

As you can see, the on "0" (start square) there are 6 circles (or tokens) and on the right side there is a datagrid view with columns showing relevant information (colour, name, money, winner).

This is what I have been able to do so far:
[image]

As you see, I have been able to show the player name, and money. Though I cannot get the colour to show up in the start square or the data grid view. Instead, I get this:

[image]

The two relevant classes are as follows:

Player.CS hold the player object code (constructors etc) (sorry for the wall of text in advance, I am unsure which parts to leave out)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace SharedGameClasses {
    /// <summary>
    /// Models a player who is currently located on a particular square 
    /// with a certain amount of money.
    /// </summary>
    public class Player {

        private const int INITIAL_AMOUNT = 100;

        // name of the player
        private string name;
        public string Name {
            get {
                return name;
            }
            set {
                name = value;
            }
        }

        // amount of money owned by player
        private int money;
        public int Money {
            get {
                return money;
            }
            set {
                money = value;
            }
        }

        // current square that player is on
        private Square location; 
        public Square Location {
            get {
                return location;
            }
            set {
                location = value;

            }
        }

        // whether the player is a winner, in the current game.
        private bool winner;
        public bool Winner {
            get {
                return winner;
            }
            set {
                winner = value;
            }
        }

        // PlayerTokenColour and PlayerTokenImage provide colours for the players' tokens (or "pieces"). 
        private Brush playerTokenColour;
        public Brush PlayerTokenColour {
            get {
                return playerTokenColour;
            }
            set {
                playerTokenColour = value;
                playerTokenImage = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(PlayerTokenImage)) {
                    g.FillRectangle(playerTokenColour, 0, 0, 1, 1);
                } 
            }
        }

        private Image playerTokenImage;
        public Image PlayerTokenImage {
            get {
                return playerTokenImage;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parameterless constructor.
        /// Do not want the generic default constructor to be used
        /// as there is no way to set the player's name.
        /// This replaces the compiler's generic default constructor.
        /// Pre:  none
        /// Post: ALWAYS throws an ArgumentException.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>NOT TO BE USED!</remarks>
        public Player() {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameterless constructor invalid.");
        } // end Player constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor with initialising parameters.
        /// Pre:  name to be used for this player.
        /// Post: this player object has all attributes initialised
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Name for this player</param>
        public Player(String name, Square initialLocation, Brush playerToken){

            Name = name;
            location = initialLocation;
            Money = INITIAL_AMOUNT;
            PlayerTokenColour = playerToken;


            //######################### Code needs to be added here ##########################################

        } // end Player constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// Rolls the two dice to determine 
        ///     the number of squares to move forward; and
        ///     moves the player's location along the board; and
        ///     obtains the effect of landing on their final square.
        /// Pre:  dice are initialised
        /// Post: the player is moved along the board and the effect
        ///     of the location the player landed on is applied.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="d1">first die</param>
        /// <param name="d2">second die</param>
        public void Play(Die d1, Die d2){

           var roll1 = d1.Roll();
           var roll2 = d2.Roll();

            int numofSquares = roll1 + roll2;

            Move(numofSquares);


            //######################### Code needs to be added here ##########################################

        } // end Play.

        /// <summary>
        /// Moves player the required number of squares forward
        /// Pre:  the number of squares to move forward
        /// Post: the player is moved along the board.
        /// NOTE: Refer to Square.cs regarding the NextSquare property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="numberOfSquares">the number of squares to move</param>
        private void Move(int numberOfSquares) {



            //######################### Code needs to be added here ##########################################3

        } //end Move

        /// <summary>
        /// Increments the player's money by amount
        /// Pre:  amount > 0
        /// Post: the player's money amount is increased.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="amount">increment amount</param>
        public void Credit(int amount) {

            Money = Money + amount;

        } //end Credit


        /// <summary>
        /// Decreases the player's money by amount if 
        ///     the player can afford it; otherwise,
        ///     sets the player's money to 0.
        /// Pre:  amount > 0
        /// Post: player's money is decremented by amount if possible
        ///       but final amount is not below zero
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="amount">decrement amount</param>
        public void Debit(int amount){

            const int loseamount = 25;

            if (Money >= 25){
                Money = Money - loseamount;
            } else if (Money < 25){
                Money = 0;
            }

            //######################### Code needs to be added here ##########################################3
        } //end Debit


    } //end class Player
}
```

And HareandTortoiseGame.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;

using System.ComponentModel;  // for BindingList.

namespace SharedGameClasses {
    /// <summary>
    /// Plays a game called Hare and the Tortoise
    /// </summary>
    public static class HareAndTortoiseGame {

    // Minimum and maximum players per game
    private const int MIN_PLAYERS = 2;
    public const int MAX_PLAYERS = 6;

    // The dice
    private static Die die1 = new Die(), die2 = new Die();

    // A BindingList is like an array that can grow and shrink. 
    // 
    // Using a BindingList will make it easier to implement the GUI with a DataGridView
    private static BindingList<Player> players = new BindingList<Player>();
    public static BindingList<Player> Players {
        get {
            return players;
        }
    }


    private static int numberOfPlayers = 6;  // The value 6 is purely to avoid compiler errors.

    public static int NumberOfPlayers {
        get {
            return numberOfPlayers;
        }
        set {
            numberOfPlayers = value;
        }
    }

    // Is the current game finished?
    private static bool finished = false;
    public static bool Finished {
        get {
            return finished;
        }
    }

    /// Some default player names.  
    /// 
    /// These are purely for testing purposes and when initialising the players at the start
    /// 
    /// These values are intended to be read-only.  I.e. the program code should never update this array.
    private static string[] defaultNames = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six" };

    // Some colours for the players' tokens (or "pieces"). 
    private static Brush[] playerTokenColours = new Brush[MAX_PLAYERS] { Brushes.Black, Brushes.Red, 
                                                          Brushes.Gold, Brushes.GreenYellow, 
                                                          Brushes.Fuchsia, Brushes.White };



    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises each of the players and adds them to the players BindingList.
    /// This method is called only once, when the game first startsfrom HareAndTortoiseForm.
    ///
    /// Pre:  none.
    /// Post: all the game's players are initialised.
    /// </summary>
    public static void InitialiseAllThePlayers(){


        //Player Playerone = new Player(defaultNames[1], Board.Squares[0]);
        int i = 0;

        while (i < NumberOfPlayers){
            players.Add(new Player(defaultNames[i], Board.Squares[0], playerTokenColours[i]));
            i++;
        }







        //##################### Code needs to be added here. ############################################################

    } // end InitialiseAllThePlayers


    /// <summary>
    /// Puts all the players on the Start square.
    /// Pre:  none.
    /// Post: the game is reset as though it is being played for the first time.
    /// </summary>
    public static void SetPlayersAtTheStart() {


        //##################### Code needs to be added here. ############################################################


    } // end SetPlayersAtTheStart


    public static void PlayOneRound(){

        InitialiseAllThePlayers();

    }






} //end class HareAndTortoiseGame
}
```

Any help/tips will be appreciated, thanks! If you need any more information let me know

EDIT: Additionally, I believe these methods from another class (HareandTortoiseForm.cs) are relevant

```
  /// <summary>
            /// Constructor with initialising parameters.
            /// Pre:  none.
            /// Post: the form is initialised, ready for the game to start.
            /// </summary>
            public HareAndTortoiseForm() {
                InitializeComponent();
                HareAndTortoiseGame.NumberOfPlayers = HareAndTortoiseGame.MAX_PLAYERS; // Max players, by default.
                HareAndTortoiseGame.InitialiseAllThePlayers();
                Board.SetUpBoard();
                SetupTheGui();
                ResetGame();
        }
```

And also ResetGame() which is where I think I am going wrong (i think this where i need to add code)

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Resets the game, including putting all the players on the Start square.
        /// This requires updating what is displayed in the GUI, 
        /// as well as resetting the attrtibutes of HareAndTortoiseGame .
        /// This method is used by both the Reset button and 
        /// when a new value is chosen in the Number of Players ComboBox.
        /// Pre:  none.
        /// Post: the form displays the game in the same state as when the program first starts 
        ///       (except that any user names that the player has entered are not reset).
        /// </summary>
        private void ResetGame() {

            // ########################### Code needs to be written  ###############################################
        }
```

EDIT 2:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Tells you which SquareControl object is associated with a given square number.
        /// Pre:  a valid squareNumber is specified; and
        ///       the boardTableLayoutPanel is properly constructed.
        /// Post: the SquareControl object associated with the square number is returned.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="squareNumber">The square number.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns the SquareControl object associated with the square number.</returns>
        private SquareControl SquareControlAt(int squareNumber) {
            int rowNumber;
            int columnNumber;
            MapSquareNumToScreenRowAndColumn(squareNumber, out rowNumber, out columnNumber);

            // Uncomment the following line once you've added the boardTableLayoutPanel to your form.
            return (SquareControl) boardTableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition(columnNumber, rowNumber);

            // Delete the following line once you've added the boardTableLayoutPanel to your form.
           // return null;
        } //end SquareControlAt
```

Comment: I know you're probably forced to use winforms for this, but still, you're much better off doing this in WPF, where you can do this in 5 minutes and avoid all the horrible hacks required in winforms to do anything, because it doesn't really support custom graphics. I mean, it's ok as a learning exercise, but there's no way you will use winforms for anything like this in the real world, except, of course if you're maintaining a legacy application from 10 years ago.

Comment: Yeah that's the basic concept behind the exercise, to give a "real word" scansion where we have to complete an unfinished project.

Comment: ask your teacher/professor/whatever if you're allowed to use current technology for this. If so, you can achieve this in 5 seconds in WPF. If not, ask him/her what's the benefit of learning the quirks of an obsolete technology that doesn't really support and is not intended for what you're doing and that you're probably never going to use in real life to do anything like this anyways. (that's what I would do, which is why I never went to school anyways)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you on placing the tokens on `DataGridView`, but I would rather change the whole board into a `TableLayoutPanel`. That way you can easily handle each cell separately, and tokens could be just some controls, which are set visible or not.

Comment: It is a tablelayoutpanel, sorry if that wasn't clear in the OP

Comment: Ok then. Now, you could add to each cell six controls with appropriate token images, which are then switched visible/invisible according to what square the token is in. Or, you can do that in a more dynamic way by creating those controls then the token enters (and leaves) a square.

Comment: If you are stuck and don't know where to begin, then I advice you to first display something easy, like text labels. I wouldn't start drawing any graphics, but work on controls only.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think there is a methodfor what your are talking about already, in a HareandTortoiseForm.cs class as follows : (refer to edit 2 in OP)

Answer (score 0):

The Colors should be shown by simply assigning them to the relevant `Cells` of the `DataGridView`:

```
DGV.Rows[playerIndex].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = playerColor;
```

The Tokens probably ought to be drawn

- either on a `Bitmap` you display in a `PictureBox`
- or directly on a `Panel` in its `Paint` event.

Both options are OK. Does this token area change during the game? 
Is there an indication in the project that can give you a hint..?

In both cases you will need the `Graphics.FillEllipse` method.